# Sonar scanner not honoring the quality gates for code smells

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I want to have a quality gates defined such that efforts required to fix all code smells is not more than 5days(say). I defined the criteria as "Technical Debt" "is greater than" "7000" (in mins). Currently I have around 7days of code smell its quality gates pass. Following are screenshots,

[image]

I am using Sonar Server 6.7.1

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong here ?

Atul Sureka

Comment: Not sure how ti works in Sonar 6.7.1, but in my 5.6.6. condition means when its passed, so if you want an error at 5 days, then I guess you should set `is less then 7200`- (5*24*60 {days*hours*mins} ). I am also not sure if the unit is the mins, but makes sense. Then you should got error at 5 more days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my math, you've set your condition at just short of 14.6 days:

`7000 / 60 / 8 = 14.583`

SonarQube uses an 8 hour day since very few people work 24h/day (for very long!) :-)

Comment: Thanks, I would update the gates according to 8 hours factor. Just curious, I was using same value (7000) with 5.6 version, is this a change which happened in sonar server 6.7.1?

Comment: IIRC in 5.6 you had the ability to tune hours per day. But that was a long time ago, so I may not "RC"